# Using Google Analytics and GTM with Classic Content Microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites, google-analytics

We have a Classic Content Microsite and I've learned that a basic level of tracking already exists through MC. However our team is interested in exploring the potential of using Google Analytics to see if we can glean more useful insights. We are not yet interested in the GA 360 integration with Sf although perhaps we will be down the line. At the moment I just need to set it up. Has anyone used GTM and/or GA with their classic content microsite. Is the setup the same as it would be on any other website? Are their any issues to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic GTM/GA setup is no different on microsites and Cloud Pages, compared to any other website. Unless you want to pass specific information to GTM data layer from e.g. AmpScript, you just need to copy & paste the basic GA JavaScript into your microsite pages.